# design pattern for class with add, update, get operations

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have a class `User` contains these **attributes**:

```
private string GSM;
private int ID;
private string SessionID;
private string SIM;
```

Also, it has these **static methods:**

```
public static bool isExistedGSM(string GSM){
    return false;
}
public static bool isExistedSIM(string SIM){
    return false;
}
public static User CreateNewUser(int ID, string SIM, string GSM){
    return new User(ID, SIM, GSM);
}
```

In addition, it contains this **local function**:

```
public void updateSesssionID(string newSessionID){
    this.SessionID = new SessionID;
}
get and set functions for all attributes
```

Is there any design patter better to help me do the same functionality but in better architecture?

***Any suggestions would be appreciated***

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I can't really understand what `isExisted...` means.

You probably want to move CreateNewUser to some user Factory (that's a design pattern).

Also, updateSessionID should be just setSessionID - just like in JavaBeans.

BTW: Is it Java or C#? stick to one convention - start methods with upper or lower case, but don't mix them. The same goes with field names.

Comment: Dear Mr. @FilipMalczak, Thanks for your valuable answer, I am using both Java and C# in my server. Also, I will take care about capitalization. In conclusion, do you suggest that I should use **(learn more)** about _user Factory_ design patter?

Comment: Nope, FACTORY is a design pattern. Also, my suggestion is to leave update... methods and stick to (is/get)/set.